# ERROR: The total invoiced amount for xxxxxx@gmail.com does not match the amount in the pay for delayed chain payment

Tags: paypal

Error:

> The total invoiced amount for xxxxxx@gmail.com does not match the amount in the pay for delayed chain payment.

I am not getting correct response for `setPaymentOptions` as here I am passing equal amount for both `payrequst` and invoice data but unable to compare their price. Is this because of currency code  as here we pass currency code for `payRequest` receiver and for invoice data? We don't have any parameter as such for passing currency code. Can anyone help me out for this please?

```
PayPal\Types\AP\SetPaymentOptionsResponse Object
 (
[responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
    (
        [timestamp] => 2016-08-25T00:11:21.138-07:00
        [ack] => Failure
        [correlationId] => 8cc5bbe5cde59
        [build] => 24003818
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
            (
                [errorId] => 580023
                [domain] => PLATFORM
                [subdomain] => Application
                [severity] => Error
                [category] => Application
                [message] => The total invoiced amount for xxxxxx@gmail.com does not match the amount in the pay request
                [exceptionId] => 
                [parameter] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorParameter Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [value] => invoiceData
                            )

                        [1] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorParameter Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [value] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Parameters I am passing for `PayRequest` and `InvoiceDatas`:

```
PayPal\Types\AP\PayRequest Object
(
[requestEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope Object
    (
        [detailLevel] => 
        [errorLanguage] => en_US
    )

[clientDetails] => 
[actionType] => PAY_PRIMARY
[cancelUrl] => http://localhost.xyz.com/paymentError?cancel=true
[currencyCode] => USD
[feesPayer] => 
[ipnNotificationUrl] => http://replaceIpnUrl.com
[memo] => 
[pin] => 
[preapprovalKey] => 
[receiverList] => PayPal\Types\AP\ReceiverList Object
    (
        [receiver] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver Object
                    (
                        [amount] => 2.00
                        [email] => ABC-facilitator@gmail.com
                        [phone] => 
                        [primary] => false
                        [invoiceId] => 
                        [paymentType] => 
                        [paymentSubType] => 
                        [accountId] => 
                    )

                [1] => PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver Object
                    (
                        [amount] => 8.00
                        [email] => xxxxxxx@gmail.com
                        [phone] => 
                        [primary] => true
                        [invoiceId] => 
                        [paymentType] => 
                        [paymentSubType] => 
                        [accountId] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError] => 
[senderEmail] => 
[returnUrl] => http://localhost.xyz.com/expressCallback
[trackingId] => 
[fundingConstraint] => 
[sender] => 
[payKeyDuration] => 
 )
 PayPal\Types\AP\ReceiverOptions Object
(
[description] => 
[customId] => 
[invoiceData] => PayPal\Types\AP\InvoiceData Object
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Types\AP\InvoiceItem Object
                    (
                        [name] => Brand
                        [identifier] => 1
                        [price] => 8.00
                        [itemPrice] => 8.00
                        [itemCount] => 32
                    )

            )

        [totalTax] => 2
        [totalShipping] => 27
    )

[receiver] => PayPal\Types\AP\ReceiverIdentifier Object
    (
        [email] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
        [phone] => 
        [accountId] => 
    )

[referrerCode] => 
)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more details regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 things are to be corrected related to price/amount to get rid of the error.

1: In the **InvoiceItem** object

```
[name] => Brand
[identifier] => 1
[price] => 256            //THIS IS EQUAL TO itemPrice * itemCount
[itemPrice] => 8.00
[itemCount] => 32
enter code here
```

---

2: In the **Reciever** object

xxxxxxx@gmail.com being the primary receiver should always have the amount equal to the total order amount (item + tax + discount + shipping), irrespective of if the secondary receiver is available or not. So it should be corrected to:

```
[amount] => 285.00                   //256 + 2 + 27
[email] => xxxxxxx@gmail.com
[phone] => 
[primary] => true
[invoiceId] => 
[paymentType] => 
[paymentSubType] => 
[accountId] =>
```

And this Receiver object of secondary receiver specifies that out of total 285.00, 2.00 will be credited to the secondary receiver:

```
[amount] => 2.00                     //2.00 will be credited to ABC out of 285.00
[email] => ABC-facilitator@gmail.com
[phone] => 
[primary] => false
[invoiceId] => 
[paymentType] => 
[paymentSubType] => 
[accountId] =>
```

Correct these and do let me know if you are still facing issue with amount mismatch.